# How do I consume a WCF web service with net.tcp binding in ColdFusion?

Tags: wcf, coldfusion, net.tcp

How do I consume a WCF web service with net.tcp binding in ColdFusion?  CreateObject gave me an error:  wrong WSDL format.  I have no problem consuming it in another Windows Form app though.  If I use http binding, I have no problem consuming it either.

Comment: NetTcp is .NET; as far as I know, for other non-.NET clients to consume your service you'll have to use one of *HttpBindings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply wsdl2javaargs flags supplying the username and password in order for the ColdFusion server to read the "imports" files that WCF uses, instead of having an all-in-one page for the wsdl.

E.g.

```
<cfset yourPassword="whatever">
<cfset yourUsername="whoever">
<cfobject type="webservice" 
          name="ws_eWard" 
          webservice="http://url.to.web-service.org/yourWebService.svc?wsdl"
          password="#yourPassword#"
          username="#yourUsername#"
          wsdl2javaargs="-U #yourUsername# -P #yourPassword#" >
```

Found this pointer at:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/642095